# Angular 8 read/render JSON file

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I have a gallery, that has images, date and some description. I have all  that information in a separate file and with the help of Angular Bootstrap carousel want to have a nice image carousel in my gallery component.

I am having trouble loading my JSON file, I don't seem to be rendering it conrrectly! Any input is much appreciated!

Below my gallery component:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbCarouselConfig } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import * as dataJSON from './gallery-data.json';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-gallery',
    templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [NgbCarouselConfig]
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
    images : any[] = [];
    readJSON = dataJSON;
    
    constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
        //customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
        config.interval = 10000;
        config.wrap = false;
        config.keyboard = true;
        config.pauseOnHover = false;

        this.images = this.readJSON.imgArray;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

```html
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
    <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let slide of images; index as i">
        <div class="gallery_container">
            <div class="gallery_img">
                <figure>
              <img [src]="slide.img" alt="Random first slide">
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="gallery_description">
    <div class="description_date">
     {{slide.date}}
    </div>
    <div class="description_text">
                    {{slide.description}}
    </div>
   </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

And my JSON file:

```css
{ "imgArray": [
{"img" : "assets/images/12.jpg", "date" : "August 18th, 2018", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/7.jpg", "date" : "February 20th, 2018", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/16.jpg", "date" : "August 20th, 2018", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/15.jpg", "date" : "March 1st, 2017", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/4.jpg", "date" : "August 20th, 2018", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/12.jpg", "date" : "July 20th, 2019", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/18.jpg", "date" : "August 14th, 2018", "description": "Lorem lorem"}, 
{"img" : "assets/images/13.jpg", "date" : "October 20th, 2019", "description": "Lorem lorem"} 
]
}
```

I am not getting any error as is, but I think my JSON data is not being loaded!

I have set `resolveJsonModule` to `true`!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `resolveJsonModule` to true in the `compilerOptions` section of tsconfig.json. I believe this is necessary to resolve json files.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule

Comment: Yes do that and then Import like so... ```import { dataJSON } from './gallery-data.json;```

Answer (score 0):

So as per your suggesestions I figured out the answer:

I imported the array as so, because the name of the array in the json file is `imgArray`

```html
import  { imgArray } from './gallery-data.json';
```

That array I put into an array of `images`:

```js
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
    images : any[] = [];    
    constructor(config: NgbCarouselConfig) {
        //customize default values of carousels used by this component tree
        config.interval = 10000;
        config.wrap = false;
        config.keyboard = true;
        config.pauseOnHover = false;

        this.images = imgArray;
    }

    ngOnInit() {}

}
```

And the gallery output was as expected!